# Speed up simple SQL query with LEFT JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The following query takes 56 seconds to return 18 rows. The table `criteria` contains about 14,200 records.  The table `criteria_interests` contains 42,500 records. `criteria_languages` contains 8 records.

If I remove the two `LEFT JOIN`s it works fast. In a real search query there would be conditions using the `criteria_interests` and `criteria_languages` tables.

For the `criteria_interests` and `criteria_languages` tables, I can't have any indexes except for the primary key, since the `cid` field isn't unique. Can anybody see how to speed this up?

```
SELECT criteria.id, criteria.uid
FROM   user_profile
       INNER JOIN criteria
               ON ( criteria.id = user_profile.cid )
       LEFT JOIN criteria_interests
              ON ( criteria_interests.cid = user_profile.cid )
       LEFT JOIN criteria_languages
              ON ( criteria_languages.cid = user_profile.cid )
GROUP  BY criteria.id
LIMIT  0, 18
```

Here are the results of `EXPLAIN`:

[image: MySQL Explain Results]

Comment: You can index non-unique fields.  In fact, I would index every field that you are joining or searching on.

Comment: I added a couple new indexes and also decided to change criteria.uid to be a unique field. Before I had planned to store saved searches as criteria records, but for the sake of speed I'm going to use a separate table for saved searches. The new indexes and criteria.uid being a distinct field fixed all of the lag issues and it's very fast now! Thanks for your tip. If you can, put your suggestion in an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. I really appreciate it. I just assumed indexes had to contain unique values. Still learning this stuff...

Comment: Why are you joining to `criteria_interests` and `criteria_languages`? They make no difference at all on the query (except for making it slow) - `SELECT criteria.id, criteria.uid FROM user_profile, criteria WHERE criteria.id = user_profile.cid GROUP  BY criteria.id LIMIT  0, 18` will yield whe same results without the LEFT JOINs

Comment: Just so you know, without an `ORDER BY` clause, the exact results returned by your query are subject to change without notice.  Also, your current statement appears to be relying on a dangerous mySQL 'feature' - always either 1) specify a column as part of the `GROUP BY` clause, or 2) reference the column in an aggregate function.  Anything else can (depending on query vs table layout) give subtly wrong results without warning.

Comment: @leon In the second paragraph you'll see where I say "In a real search query there would be conditions using the criteria_interests and criteria_languages tables."

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse This is just a heavily stripped down version of what the actual query would be. I isolated the problem code, which was the LEFT JOINs.

Comment: @Gavin, despite the fact your table was lacking indexes, there may be other adjustments possible to the query, but if that is enough for you, no need to push this further

Comment: @leon Since my SQL skill level is pretty low right now I'm actually positive it's not nearly as efficient as it could be. I just have to keep learning all this. I'm one of those people who has a hard time retaining stuff I read, so I have to get my hands dirty to learn it, so I really appreciate all the feedback on stackoverflow. It's very helpful.